# StackOverflow Error when processing large input data

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow, regex-lookarounds

StackOverflowError when matching the result using a RegEx pattern

I have checked other post for same kind of issue but not able to modify my regex accordingly

This my regex which is causing the problme

```
private static final Pattern comment = Pattern.compile("\\/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/[\n\r]*",
        Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

```
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4250)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4279)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
```

Comment: Could you add the `String` you are using this pattern on ?

Comment: FYI, you do not need case insensitive and dotall flags, `Pattern.compile("/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/[\n\r]*");` should be good. If it is not you need a dedicated parser.

Comment: It looks like you're running into [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Could you provide some examples of what you're trying to match? Is it multiline comments? If yes then do you intend on parsing other code as well? If yes again then I'd advice to switch to a proper parser because regex are no good fit for parsing arbitrary code.

Comment: @Arnaud string is larger the allowed size of content here

Comment: @Thomas yes but i tried to modify my regex to rectify the catastrophic backtracking. it didnt work

Comment: Well, please elaborate on what you're trying to match. That expression feels overly complicated and if not (i.e. you think you need that complexity) that might be a good indicator that regex are the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Thomas i am trying to remove multiline comment .Multiline comment can contains any character  inside the comment . for example(/,*,:,a-z,(,-.....)

Comment: @Thomas Link to my string https://github.com/monikanaagar/LargeInputString/blob/master/Inputstring

Comment: Well, what would happen if a regular string contained a "multiline commen", e.g. `String falsePositive = "/*whatever reasons I have for this*/";`? If that can't happen you could try to use the following expression to match a multiline comment: `(?s)/\*.*?\*/` - that means "anything between a `/*` and the next `*/`" - that `(?s)` is the dot-all flag, needed here because of the dot-expression `.*?`.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern isn't specially badly written, but you can improve it to limit the backtracking:

```
private static final Pattern comment = Pattern.compile("/\\*(?:\\**[^/*][^*]*)*+\\*+/[\n\r]*");
```

The two options are useless (dotall, case insensitive). I removed the strange `[^*]*\\*+` and I made quantifiers possessive when it can be useful.

This pattern is written in a hand-driven way to quickly reach asterisks.

---

Since your string isn't so long, something like:

```
private static final Pattern comment = Pattern.compile("\Q/*\E .*? \Q*/\E [\n\r]*", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

should also work.

This pattern is shorter and more readable, but eventually slower since a non-greedy quantifier needs more tests.

Comment: @MonikaNaagar: what is your input string?

Comment: @MonikaNaagar: when you say *"it didn't work"*, what do you mean? Same error as before or not the expected result?

Comment: Not the expected result. it should detect multiline comment

Comment: @MonikaNaagar: That is exactly what the pattern does! see the demo (click on the green java button): https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydx5bxyr

Comment: @MonikaNaagar: as an aside, your data aren't so large (only 57Ko).